# How to plot with fviz_pca_ind() without showing the legend?

Tags: r, visualization, pca

I want the legend to disappear. Above is an example of what I did with the iris dataset in R. 
I could not find a variable in the documentation of fviz_pca_ind() to omit the legend.

```
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)
pca_iris <- PCA(iris[ ,-5])
iris$species <- as.factor(iris$Species)
pca_n.macros_plot <- fviz_pca_ind(pca_iris, 
             pointshape = 21,habillage = iris$species,
             palette = "jco",label="none",
             geom.ind = c("point"),geom = c("point"),
             title="PCA iris")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.7/topics/fviz_pca) of fviz_pca,

the output class is `gg` or `ggplot`. Hence, below code should work for you.

```
pca_n.macros_plot + theme(legend.position = "none")
```